# GLSL Convolution with Large Kernel in Texture Memory

Tags: textures, glsl, texture2d, convolution

I'm very new to GLSL, but I'm trying to write convolution kernel with in a fragment shader for image processing.  I was able to do this just fine when my kernel was small (3x3) using a constant matrix.  Now, however, I'd like to use a kernel of size 9x9.  Or for that matter of arbitrary size.  My initial thought was to setup a texture memory containing the convolution kernel.  Then using a 2Dsampler I'd read the texture memory of the kernel and convolve it with the texture memory of the image (also a 2Dsampler).  Is this the right way to go about this?

I suppose you could also make an array of arbitrary size that contains coefficients.  This might work for 81 coefficients, but what happens if you want something larger?  Like say a 20x20?

In general if you need to access multiple large objects in GLSL what's the proper strategy?  Thanks!
Thanks,

D

Comment: Did you implement this? Can you share your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential access:

1. **Vertex Attributes**

Random access:

1. **Texture Buffers** / **Uniform blocks** if the source is a buffer
2. **Uniforms** if the source is small
3. **Textures** otherwise

Comment: Can you expand on how to use vertex attributes for this? Would one have a separate vertex attribute for each offset? Why would this be faster than using a const array of vertex indices?

Comment: @AlexFlint: my answer was to the general question ("In general if you need to access multiple large objects in GLSL what's the proper strategy?"). I wouldn't recommend using vertex attributes for storing convolution coefficients at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since uniform and constant space is limited, using a texture as replacement is a good strategy.